# How correctly test if subscriber is called with correct data in onNext() (RxJava2)

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java2

I would like to test this method:

```
void updateAvailableScreens() {
        safieCam.availableCameras()
                .flatMap(this::getAvailableScreensForCameras)
                // causing failure .observeOn(schedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        screens -> {
                            view.setAvailablePagesOnViewPager(screens);
                            view.setAvailablePagesOnBottomSheet(screens);
                        },
                        Timber::e
                );
    }
```

with this test (so giving known data, I expect calling view with expected enum list):

```
@Test
public void widgetsShouldGetAllScreens() {
    when(camera.availableCameras()).thenReturn(
            Observable.just(Arrays.asList(
                    SafieCam.CameraType.SELFIE,
                    SafieCam.CameraType.REAR)));
    testedVPPresenter.updateAvailableScreens();

    List<ViewPagerView.Pages> pages = Arrays.asList(
            ViewPagerView.Pages.SELFIE,
            ViewPagerView.Pages.REAR_CAMERA,
            ViewPagerView.Pages.LOGIN);
    verify(view).setAvailablePagesOnViewPager(pages);
    verify(view).setAvailablePagesOnBottomSheet(pages);
}
```

but when observeOn is uncommented test will fail due to zero interactions with `view`, otherwise it will succed.

Needed info:
`schedulers` is interface wrapper, and all called schedulers are mocked on tests with TestScheduler.

Question: Am I doing something wrong here? If so what is correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misused TestScheduler, because I didn't call

**`testScheduler.triggerActions()`**

after using test scheduler (in my case after `testedVPPresenter.updateAvailableScreens()`)

So all events were queued, but without execution.